# Error in MPI program execution - no active ports found

Tags: mpi

I am trying to run a simple MPI job across multiple hosts of a cluster.

```
[capc@gpu6 mpi_tests]$ /opt/openmpi4.0.3/build/bin/mpirun --host gpu7,gpu6 ./a.out

WARNING: There is at least non-excluded one OpenFabrics device found,
but there are no active ports detected (or Open MPI was unable to use
them). This is most certainly not what you wanted. Check your
cables, subnet manager configuration, etc. The openib BTL will be
ignored for this job.
Local host: gpu7
We have 2 processes.

WARNING: Open MPI accepted a TCP connection from what appears to be a
another Open MPI process but cannot find a corresponding process
entry for that peer.

This attempted connection will be ignored; your MPI job may or may not
continue properly.
Local host: gpu6
PID: 29209

[gpu6:29203] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib.txt / no active ports found
[gpu6:29203] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

I have compiled the MPI program with mpicc and on running with mpirun it hangs.

Can anyone guide me regarding this?